# iOS UI : Need guidance to design such a flow of screens - which controllers should be best?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, navigation

I am a newbie in iOS development. Sorry if my question sounds subjective or contents very simple to answer; but I couldn't get any words to describe my question briefly in Question title.

I need to design some views and to navigate between them am not sure what would be best. So need your guidance in that case.

In my Tabbed app, myTab1 shows a table on whose click app should show other screen LayoutViewController. In this view, I want a panel on top which will have 2 btns - 1 will take Back and other will show a drop down menu. And a textfield on bottom. I want these both things to be on their place only - not to scroll with other components. And on each drop down menu I want to open other view respectively like "SettingsViewController" & "TransferViewController".  I believe when Settings & Transfer task is done, it will dismiss itself & LayoutViewController will be visible.

MY concerns are :-

- How to add a panel on top ?
- How to not make top panel & bottom textfield scroll along with other components ?
- Go to Back i.e. myTab1 screen - I guess for this I should show LogoutView as Modal view from LAyoutView. Or Is their a std way to go to back in iOS.
- For drop down menu on btw click, I found [this solution](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/)

Am I planning the navigation in correct way or is their any better approach that I should opt for ! And the panel part, what to add for that ? I don't see any control like panel.

MY app is for iPhone & iPad & I use Xcode 5.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can design your application using UINavigationController and TabView as a rootViewController. For the options you can use right bart button adding an ActionSheet to the same and on selecting the same you can open different ViewController using NavigationController pushViewController. The back button will be present by default if NavigationController is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS you have a standard UInavigationController that helps you navigating trough viewcontrollers using push segues. It comes along with top and bottom bars and auto generates back buttons for you. But as these bars are not highly customisable, I usually disable them and use my own top/bottom bars and create back buttons by myself. In IOS 7 there is also a new interactivegesturerecognizer feature that allows you to swipe from the left side of the screen to go back.

I would recommend you to use a push segue/nav controller to go from tablevc to layoutvc. From layoutvc you can use modal segues to bring settings vc.

Regarding fixed/scrollable areas, each view controller has a root view, there you can add as many subviews as you like. Using autolayout or the older spring/struts method, you can stick the view to the to, bottom etc of the screen.

Comment: To go from tablevc to layoutvc - SO I should add my navigation bar in tablevc and not layoutvc, Right ???

Comment: if it's enabled, the navbar will add itself everywhere trough the navigation tree, if disabled, you create a subview as a bar and add it where you need.

Comment: I added navBar in layoutVC & in added a button at right side namely (dropDownBtn) & for back button named it "backBtn". But on clicking any btns nothing happens. From storyboard I am also not able to insert action for dropdownBtn. And I guess as navBar was added in same class hence nothing is in back - so for that I should add navBar in tableVC. But their I don't want the dropDownBtn or so. How to avoid this, also can't find any tutorial that shows how to manage such things using storyboards.   Can u please guide me with this..

Comment: there is long story here, you have to create subclasses of UIViewController and assign one for each VC in storyboard, then you'll be able to drag outlets/actions. Try the first lectures here https://itunes.apple.com/en/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Comment: I have done all that. In my tableVc, from storyboard, under Simulated Metrics - Top Bar - I selected Translucent Nav Bar, Tresn Nav Bar with Prompty, Opaque.... & I see bar space in storyboard view, but at run time I don't get any navBar. In my AppDelegate, I ale created UINavigationController *navigationController1 & added tabBarController to it & am showing [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController1]; inlace of tabBarController. Yet I don't see the navBar in my tabBarController (tableVc). What am I missing here ??

Comment: your root view controller should be embedded in a navigation controller (in storyboard select the root vc and go to editor -> embed in -> navigation controller). And what you set in the simulated metrics for the Navigation Controller VC in storyboard, will be inherited by all navigation tree. No need to set anything in appdelegate.

Comment: Ok. I embedded my root vc i.e. LoginVC in navigation controller thru storyboard. In my root vc LoginVC also added View title & Title in Navigation Item. I can see the title in storyboard, but on execution it doesn't show up. Also tried setting TopBar in LoginVC, & also tried setting in NavigationController, but no success. I have removed the text that had added in AppDelgate tp add NavController.